# React testing componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I do quite a lot of component testing with React. Finally, I'm switching between DOM (renderIntoDocument) and Shallow rendering and I have two questions:

- why componentDidMount is not triggered in Shallow rendering?
- is it possible to trigger componentWillReceiveProps with DOM approach?

Thanks

Comment: There is a thread [here](https://gist.github.com/jondlm/514405bea50fad6fd905) that asks for some way to fire componentDidMount in shallow rendering. Why it is not yet there? Probably a mix of a) shallow rendering still in development and b) shallow rendering does not render children, and componentDidMount is normally only rendered after all children are rendered. In [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30616091/5358807) there seems to be an explanation how to do update on DOM approach/ renderIntoDocument, to fire componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: Thanks @wintvelt. That's a good answer for me, if you move your comment to answer, I'll validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a thread [here](https://gist.github.com/jondlm/514405bea50fad6fd905) that asks for some way to fire `componentDidMount` in shallow rendering.

Why it is not yet there? Probably a mix of
a) shallow rendering still in development and
b) shallow rendering does not render children, and `componentDidMount` is normally only rendered after all children are rendered.

In [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614454/how-to-test-a-prop-update-on-react-component/30616091#30616091) there seems to be an explanation how to do update on DOM approach/ renderIntoDocument, to fire `componentWillReceiveProps`.