# How do I write a test for a component that uses React.cloneElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

My top level component takes `children` from `react-router` like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {React.cloneElement(children, this.props.widgets)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a simple test with `jest`, like this:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div)
})
```

However, this test fails with the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● renders without crashing

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous>.ReactElement.cloneElement (node_modules/react/lib/ReactElement.js:271:34)
      at Object.cloneElement (node_modules/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js:216:48)
      at App.render (src/App.js:50:57)
      at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:796:21
      at measureLifeCyclePerf (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:795:25)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:822:32)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:362:30)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:258:21)
      at Object.mountComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:371:34)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:258:21)
      at Object.mountComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
      at mountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:104:32)
      at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:140:20)
      at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:126:15)
      at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:140:20)
      at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
```

Is there a way to mock `cloneElement`? Or to test the component in such a way that it ignores the call to `cloneElement`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a prop update on React component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614454/how-to-test-a-prop-update-on-react-component)

Comment: Afraid not. The error message that person was receiving had the term `React.cloneElement` in it.  My question involves how to test when using `React.cloneElement`.

Comment: i think you forgot to pass the widgets props, it should be like this: `ReactDOM.render(<App widgets={some value} />, div)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `children` is undefined, because there is no router to provide a child component.

Fix it by creating a test child component:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() { return (<div className="test" />) }
}

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  ReactDOM.render(<App><TestComponent /></App>, div)
})
```