# How to update React Component props during unit tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, parent-child

I am new to React Unit Testing and am stuck with this question.

I have a child component with an `onClick` callback to its parent. The parent will then update the child `props` based on the callback. The child has a custom style based on the props value.

Something like this:

```
// Parent
const ParentComponent = () => {
    let isActive = false;
    const clickCallback = () => {
        isActive = true;
    }
    return <ChildComponent handleClick={clickCallback} active={isActive} />
}

// Child
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return <button onClick={props.handleClick} style={props.active} />
}
```

My question is: how can I test that behavior? I want to make sure that, on clicking the child component, my custom style will be updated.

I tried this approach, but it didn't work:

```
let mockIsActive = false;
const mockCallback = () => {mockIsActive = true;}
ReactDOM.render(
    <ChildComponent handleClick={mockCallback} active={mockIsActive} />, 
    container
);

const myChild = container.querySelector("button");
expect(myChild.getComputedStyle).toEqual("my check here");
myChild.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {bubbles: true}));
expect(myChild.getComputedStyle).toEqual("my new check here");
```

I am assuming that I am updating the variable but that is not really connected to the component props?

**Extra information:**

- The behavior is working fine when I run the project (custom style changes)
- I need to control the child props from the parent in my specific scenario
- I currently have `react-test-renderer` and `react-dom/test-utils`, but I am fine with including external libraries if needed
- The closest answer I found online was [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614454/how-to-test-a-prop-update-on-react-component), but I wasn't able to apply the solutions there in my project

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer to use [Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35493301/1941241) to test these things.

Comment: I'm with @rickdenhaan on Enzyme. I like Jest even more. One thing to notice here is that you should first test that your child component itself gets the correct style given props it's parent would pass. Then make sure the parent's function behaves correctly. Only then you worry about a child to parent back to child scenario, because that's really React's job

Comment: @leosteffen When you say "you should first test that your child component itself gets the correct style given props it's parent would pass", do you mean like "hardcoding" the props to make sure the right style is applied?
Good point about React's job on the communication thing.
Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro yes, hard code it. You want to make sure that your child component looks a certain way once it gets a specific value via that prop active, so you need to write a test that renders your component with that specific prop and check to see if it renders as it is supposed to.

Comment: Cool, just updated my tests to include that. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use Enzyme and Jest for testing your components, the API they provide is rich and extensive.

Let's assume you are using Enzyme, you will do it this way:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);

wrapper.find(Child).props().handleClick();
expect(wrapper.instance().isActive)).to.equal(true); // Assuming Parent is a class based component
```

My suggestion is try testing each component as a unit, that way you can cover all cases. I hope this helps you in your testing.