# How do I re-render a component in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a `beforeEach()` that renders my app:

```
describe('...', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<App />);
  });
  ...
});
```

I am currently going through a config change in my app. `config` was previously a boolean value in localStorage and now it has a more appropriate value like `prod` and `dev`. My app checks the old boolean values when it first loads and it changes them to their respective non-boolean value - here's the mapping:

```
true -> prod
false -> dev
```

I am trying to write tests for this transformation in Jest. The idea behind the first test is to set the localStorage item, re-render the app, and check the the localStorage item has been updated correctly:

```
it('should show dev config when using old boolean value', () => {
  const toggle = screen.getByTestId('toggle');
  expect(toggle).toBeChecked();
  localStorage.setItem('config', false);

  // re-render app and check localStorage
  render(<App />);
  const toggle2 = screen.getByTestId('toggle');

  expect(toggle2).not.toBeChecked();
  expect(localStorage.getItem('config')).toEqual('dev');
});
```

However, this test throws an error presumably because the app is now rendered twice instead of once:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements by: [data-id="toggle"]
```

How do I re-render the app so that it isn't duplicated in the test environment?

Comment: Similar question for enzyme https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614454/how-to-test-a-prop-update-on-react-component

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `@testing-library/react` you can use the `rerender` method that is returned from the initial `render`. You can use this method to call `render` again and provide the same container
that your first call created (you can even pass new props).

Docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-update-props/

Example:

```
it('should add the fixed width class if position is fixed', () => {
  const {rerender} = render(<PageNavigation position="fixed-left" fixedWidth="test-123" />);

  const list = screen.getByTestId('page-navigation'); // Or however you're selecting

  expect(list).toHaveClass('test-123');

  rerender(<PageNavigation position="fixed-right" fixedWidth="test-456" />);

  // Sanity check to ensure the first class was removed
  expect(list).not.toHaveClass('test-123');

  expect(list).toHaveClass('test-456');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error means that **jest cannot access a dom node with [data-id=toggle]**

because it founds more than one node with same attribute.

Instead, use matcher **"getAllByTestId('toggle')** instead of **"getByTestId('toggle)**.

This will return an array of nodes with attribute [data-id=toggle]
you can access them same way like arrays.

```
it('should show dev config when using old boolean value', () => {
  **let toggles = screen.getAllByTestId('toggle');**
  expect(toggles[0]).toBeChecked();
  localStorage.setItem('config', false);
```

.
.
.
.

For rerendering a react component in unit test, check this
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender

```
    it('should show dev config when using old boolean value', () => {
  const {rerender} = render(<App />) 
  let toggles = screen.getAllByTestId('toggle');
  expect(toggles[0]).toBeChecked();
  localStorage.setItem('config', false);

  // re-render app and check localStorage
  rerender(<App />);
  toggles = screen.getAllByTestId('toggle');

  expect(toggles[1]).not.toBeChecked();
  expect(localStorage.getItem('config')).toEqual('dev');
});
```